# Scaffold-DbContext throws error "Could not find assembly" in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-core, scaffolding

I am using .net core and entity framework core 1.1.0. while trying the following command in **Package Manager Console**

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MyServer\\MyInstance;Database=MyDB;user=MyUsername;password=MyDbPassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -t Table1,Table2
```

I am getting this error

> Could not find assembly
>   'D:\Work\Projects\src\MyProject\src\MyProject.Api.\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64\MyProject.Data.exe'.

MyProject.Data is a net core library. MyProject.Api is a .net full framework core api, which references the MyProject.Data.

project.json file of MyProject.Data

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
  }
}
```

Any advice for me?

Comment: You may want to try using the .NET Command Line tools: `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ...`

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this is a bug, but `scaffold-dbcontext` command looks for the assembly in **Startup Project**.

There are two workarounds for this issue

1. Right click on the project you intend to run this command on (in your case, it is MyProject.Data) and select **Set as startup project**.
2. You can pass a parameter to `scaffold-DBContext` command to set a particular project as startup project while running the command.
   This is what you need to add at the end of command...

`-StartupProject MyProject.Data`

Comment: Worked for me doing -StartupProject MyProject.Data, many thanks

Comment: Yes!! This works
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;Database=MyDbName;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0" -StartupProject MyProject -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force

Answer (score 7):

It seems that this issue also occurs if the target platform is x86.

Switching to AnyCPU solves the problem.

Comment: Agree, had the same problem. Ty

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to scaffold a FireBird database.
The first issue is that the FireBird file was made in 32bit.
Because of that, my project had to target x86.
I had then messages "could not load assembly ensure it is referenced  by the startup project".
The solution to remove those messages was :

- if using Firebird in **embedded** mode (without having to run a server instance) download the **x86 Firebird package**, copy `fbembed.dll` `icudt30.dll` `icuuc30.dll` `msvcr80.dll` side by side with the csproj
- install the **x86 net sdk**
- add `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\` in the system environment variables **above** `C:\Program Files\dotnet\`
- in Powershell **x86** : `& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe' ef dbcontext scaffold "ServerType=1;Database=PATH_TO_THE_FDB;user id=THE_USER;password=THE_PASSWORD" FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird --configuration=debug --verbose`, ServerType=1 is for using Firebird in embedded mode

What helped me to go down this path was [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22594), [Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) then helped me to see that the dotnet process was in x64.