# Nuget Error on Scaffold-DBContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use the Scaffold-DBContext but it throws me error when i try to run it on the Package Console Manager. 
 It throws this error:  
 `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String contentRootPath, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String environment)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DbContextScaffoldCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)`

Basically it says that it cant find the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Assembly.
I already checked and it's installed. 

**EDIT:**
I've installed the following packages via the console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

Comment: Which package do you installed?  Can you tell how you install the package?

Comment: I'll edit my question with the packages i've installed

Comment: I've just found the answer in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804083/scaffold-dbcontext-throws-error-could-not-find-assembly-in-net-core

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/)

Comment: It's already installed

Comment: You didn't list that in your packages you installed. What is the full list you have in your `.csproj`?

Comment: I listed the ones i installed myself